# Fetch data by a condition react native node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, fetch

Im trying to fetch some specific data from my database , To be more specific and clear here is an exemple:
i have clients in my database , and here is how their documents looks like:

Client 1:
_id:xxx
name:abc
credit:100

Client 2:
_id:yyy
name:abcde
credit:0

i want to display  the data of the clients who have an credit > 0 in a flatlist

i already have an flatlist which displays all data and it works fine ,
i hope i was clear, thanks!

Im using react native-nodejs

```
    class Listtest extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.delayValue = 8000;
    this.state = {
  
    animatedValue: new Animated.Value(0),
    search:'',
    refreshing: true,
    dataSource: [],
    isLoading:true
    }
    }

    onPresss = (item) => {
    const Designation = item.Designation;
    const Marque = item.Marque;
    const PrixAchat = item.PrixAchat;
    const PrixVente = item.PrixVente;
    const MaxRemise = item.MaxRemise;
    const QuantiteAlerte = item.QuantiteAlerte;
    const QuantiteArticle = item.QuantiteArticle;
    const Id_fournisseur = item.Id_fournisseur;
    }


    renderItem = ({item}) => {
    this.delayValue = this.delayValue + 500;
    const translateX = this.state.animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [this.delayValue,1]
    });
    return(
    <Animated.View
    style={[styles.button, { transform: [{ translateX }] }]}>
    
    <View style={{flex:1}}>

    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={()=>this.onPresino(item)}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',padding:10}}> 
    
    <Avatar.Image
     source={{uri:'https://i.ibb.co/xDJ6XBd/Articleimage.jpg'}}
     size={50}/>
    <Text style= 
    {{marginVertical:10,marginLeft:20,letterSpacing:1.7,fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:20,marginLeft:8}}> 
    {item.Designation}</Text> 

    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
    </Animated.View>
    )
    }
    renderSeparator =() => {
    return(
    <View
    style={{height:1,width:'100%',backgroundColor:'#ccc'}}>

    </View>
    )
    }

     async componentDidMount() {
     Animated.spring(this.state.animatedValue, {
     toValue: 1,
     tension: 20,
     useNativeDriver: true
     }).start();
     await fetch ('http://localhost:8080/api/articles',{
     method:'get',
     mode:'no-cors',
     headers:{
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
     },

     })

    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
    dataSource:responseJson
    })
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
    console.log(error)
    }
    )}


 render(){

   return (

   <View style={styles.container}>

    <SearchBar
    placeholder="Tapez ici..."
    onChangeText={search => { this.setState({ search }) }}
    value={this.state.search}
    style={styles.search}
    round="default"
    lightTheme="default"
  />
  
       <FlatList
        pagingEnabled
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        
        
      />

    </View>


     )}}

     const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      height: 300,
      flex:1,

      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      borderRadius: 6,
    },
                   
     });
    export default Listtest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
<FlatList
  pagingEnabled
  data={this.state.dataSource.filter((value)=> value.credit > 0 )}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
/>
```

you can change `0` with a state value to have more control over it.